# Record-Triggered Flow not running as the specified automated user

Tags: visual-workflow, permissions, user, screen-flow, guest-user

1. **Screen-Flow:** customer-facing webform executed in User Context as a Guest User. This Flow simply creates a Case.
2. **Record-Triggered Flow:** triggered when a Record is created, running other queries and making some changes to the triggering Record. It is executed After the Record is saved in the db, and runs as Integration User.

*Both Flows work perfectly in isolation.* However, if a Record is created by Flow #1, Flow #2 fails due to permission issues. This does not make sense at all since Flow #2 is executed by Integration User, which does have all the necessary permissions.

Any clues on what could be happening here? Why is the Record-Triggered Flow running as the Guest User?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful

Comment: record-triggered flows run in the context of the running user unless it is a scheduled path in which case the running user is defined in Process Automation Settings. You have to make Flow#2 [accessible to the Guest User Profile](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_flow_guestuser.htm&type=5)